# I am getting the exit code 1 for fetching the submodule in git hub action

Tags: python-3.x, azure, github-actions, action, git-submodules

I am using the git hub actions to deploy to app service but i am unable to fetch the submodule and getting exit code as 1

I tried by creating PAT token in the settings and authorizes SSO but i am getting the exit code 1 when i am fetching the submodule from yml file in git hub action.

```
Fetching the repository
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +refs/heads/v2*:refs/remotes/origin/v2* +refs/tags/v2*:refs/tags/v2*
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 1
  Waiting 16 seconds before trying again
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +refs/heads/v2*:refs/remotes/origin/v2* +refs/tags/v2*:refs/tags/v2*
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 1
  Waiting 16 seconds before trying again
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +refs/heads/v2*:refs/remotes/origin/v2* +refs/tags/v2*:refs/tags/v2*
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I have added the token and i tried the below method it is not working for submodule then i am trying by using git config getting  could not read the username

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set up the PAT token correctly in the ***Github Secrets and variable > Actions*** and reference it correctly by using the github action script like below:-

**YAML Code:-**

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Checkout Repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      submodules: 'recursive'
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PatToken }}
```

```yaml
- name: Initialize and Update Submodules
  run: |
    git submodule update --init --recursive
```

**You can add the debugging steps in your workflow like below:-**

```yaml
- name: Debug Git Config
  run: |
    git config --list
- name: Fetch Submodule with Debugging
  run: |
    git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I tried the ***below github action workflow and the Deployment was successful like below***:-

**My github action workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - valleywebapp09

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: Initialize and update submodules
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'valleywebapp09'
          slot-name: 'production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_xxxx25a8xxx }}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: are you using only main.yml to download submodules are you included the above pat file as well in your yml file

Comment: I tried which you provided the yaml and i am getting the error fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address at the time of run of submodule

Comment: Is the secret added correctly in the github repository > Settings > Secrets and variable Actions? Also cross verify the PAT once, If verified correctly try this code- - name: Initialize and update submodules with PAT
        run: |
          git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.SUBMODULE_PAT }}@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
          git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: yes the secret added correctly in the settings in parent and i tried with the above one in yml file but still i am getting the same error

Comment: name: clone submodule
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: recursive
      - name: Configure Git for Private Submodule
        run: |
         git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf "https://ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/"
         
         git config --global credential.helper store
         git config --global user.email "my mail id"
         git config --global user.name "myusername"
         env:
         ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}

Comment: - name: Update Submodule
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: the above steps i added in the yml after requirements.txt fule

Comment: My repo is private repo for submodule and please let me know in PAT if there is any specific permissions required

Comment: I have one query is it required to mention our url right for this one https://${{ secrets.SUBMODULE_PAT }}@github.com/".insteadOf "github.com"